# Django annotate Concat - Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field

Tags: django, annotate

I have a model:

```
class Motocycle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
    engine_displacement = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and I want to:

```
queryset = Motocycle.objects.annotate(
    full_name=Concat(
        'title',
         Value(' '),
         F('engine_displacement'),
         Value('')
    ),
).all()
```

But got an error: `Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field`:

```
queryset = Motocycle.objects.annotate(
    full_name=Concat(
        'title',
         Value(' '),
         F('engine_displacement'),
         Value(''),
    ),
    output_field=CharField(),
).all()
```

I tryed to set this `output_field`, result was: `'CharField' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'`.

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must pass `output_field` to your db function, in your code you pass it to annotate.

```
queryset = Motocycle.objects.annotate(
    full_name=Concat(
        'title',
         Value(' '),
         F('engine_displacement'),
         Value(''),
         output_field=CharField(),
    ),
).all()
```